# AVPlay for Tizen, ploblem with getting duration of video

Tags: javascript, tizen

I have a problem with getting information from current playing video in AVPay. The problem is that when i am trying to getDuration() as showed in [API](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/multimedia/media-playback/using-avplay)

```
if(webapis.avplay.getState() == "READY")
{
    console.log(webapis.avplay.getDuration());
}
```

Shows: "NaN"

Answer (score 0):

You can try-catch that block and see what error message is caught. I suspect you might call it in the wrong state of the AVPlay API, as it's available only when the player is in state PLAYING or PAUSED according to the documentation.

Another possibility is that you are using the emulator and this is an unsupported function. However I don't think it was, also they usually return dummy values.

Comment: Would you mind marking the reply as the correct answer?

Comment: You were right with that the emulator can not display. i mean it works in real TV devices